# Sheets - Script - Limit number of rows imported from a CSV using a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a script that's importing a CSV from a location on G-Drive - I just need it to import the first 300 rows, as opposed to all 2000 rows. What am I missing?

```js
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxx'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv is saved
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("content.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Comment: Haven't tested this myself, but try adding `csvData.splice(299,csvData.length-300);` on the line after you define it.

Comment: Wonderful - that worked Ross! Knew it would be something straight forward :)

Comment: Thanks Ross. Random follow up you might be able to help with before I make a separate question - someone pointed out to me filtering my file selection directly by name may not work, as the users of this spreadsheet may upload copies (I.e. content(1).csv). 

Is there a way I can getFilesBy latest file in the folder?

Comment: Not sure that's possible with a simple method, you'll need some sort of loop to compare the dates OR use a method in the Drive API. Probably best to post another question as I don't think there's a simple one-line answer for that one.

Answer (score 1):

**First 300 lines of csv file**

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxx'); 
  var files = folder.getFilesByName("content.csv");
  var n=0;
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    n++;
  }
  if(n==1) {
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()).slice(0,300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("More Than One File with that name");
  }
}
```

[Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

I tested with a csv file of my own.